# Ajax на чистом js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть код на jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'site.com/ajax?meow=true',           
    success: function (data, textStatus) { 
       //получен response, находится в data
    } 
});
```

Надо добиться такого же результата на js. Сделать `get` к `site.com/ajax?meow=true` и получить `response` в какую-нибудь перемененную. **Как?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Взято тут: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp)

ActiveX, в принципе, можете уже не учитывать, остановившись на

> // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome,
> Opera, Safari

Ответ:

```
var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: А то что здесь значиться xml - это просто название или что-то имеется ввиду? Просто response будет совсем не xml -ный, и я его (респонз) буду пропускать через eval().

Comment: ответ в текстовом виде. В любом случае. Просто изначально ориентировались именно на xml